# How to install pip library in ec2-instance virtual environment using user data?

Tags: python, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pip

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIk31.jpg)I am try to install **pip libraries** in ec2-instances virtual environment using **user data**.

But while I am trying that I will create at **instance** level but not at virtual environment level.

What I need exactly is will I am creating **ec2-instance** on **configuration** level I want to define that to create **pip libraries** at **virtual environment** level.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sudo yum update
sudo yum install python3 pip3 -y
sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip 
pip install --upgrade pip
python3 -m venv /home/ec2-user/vertual-Environment
pip install django
pip install djangorestframework
pip install pillow
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to **source** your python env envrionment.

Example (I have **verified** now the code on Amazon Linux 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install python3 python3-pip -y
sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip 
pip install --upgrade pip
python3 -m venv /home/ec2-user/vertual-Environment

# source your new python env
source /home/ec2-user/vertual-Environment/bin/activate

pip install django
pip install djangorestframework
pip install pillow
```

Comment: I tried your script but not activate i submitted output image above thanks for your response.

Comment: @rajeevpunna There are other mistakes, such as `missing -y` in `sudo yum update`. So your script will never execute waiting for manual confirmation of the update or the fact that `pip3` package does not exist.

Comment: @rajeevpunna I fixed everything and can verity that it works.

Comment: Still, it's not working it fix on update issue only. But it will not source /home/ec2-user/vertual-Environment/bin/activate --activate this one.

Comment: @rajeevpunna I varrified that it works. Please double check your steps. The code successful creates `/home/ec2-user/vertual-Environment` with the django and pillow installed in the environment. Maybe you are using it on different linux than Amazon Linux 2.

Answer (score 0):

Using user data, your should install your dependencies this way :

```py
python3 -m venv /home/ec2-user/vertual-Environment
/home/ec2-user/vertual-Environment/bin/pip install django
/home/ec2-user/vertual-Environment/bin/pip install djangorestframework
/home/ec2-user/vertual-Environment/bin/pip install pillow
```

When using userdata, your script are executed independently, regardless of what have been done in previous executions.